# Extract Files from a log file

Tags: powershell

I need help with a logfile that I need information extracted into another file and I'm having difficulty deciding which method to use.

```
LogFile:
2019-01-14 21:36:36 INFO: Starting script execution
2019-01-14 21:36:36 INFO: Execution date is 1/14/2019 9:36:36 PM
2019-01-14 21:36:36 INFO: Script version is 1.1.6
2019-01-14 21:36:37 INFO: Executing forest is adroot.
2019-01-14 21:36:37 WARNING: Executing domain is office.adroot.
2019-01-14 21:36:37 INFO: Executing user is OFFICE\adaccountdeletion
```

Basically, I need to search the logfile for INFO the script continues and WARNING the script grabs that line and outputs it to a logfile. I'm not sure if I should use Regex or If else statements and how I would. So far I have this:

```
$input_path = 'H:\REPO\ADCLEAN\testlog.log'
$output_file = 'H:\REPO\ADCLEAN\Output.txt'
Get-Content ‘INFO’ >>$output_file
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $content -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will grab the lines that contain **WARNING:** and output (using append) to your file:

```
"WARNING" | Add-Content $output_file
(Get-Content $input_path) -cmatch "WARNING:" | Add-Content $output_file
```

The following will grab the lines that contain **INFO:** and output (using append) to your file:

```
"INFO" | Add-Content $output_file
(Get-Content $input_path) -cmatch "INFO:" | Add-Content $output_file
```

Comment: Thank you this worked well, on a side note would you know how to get an alert to pop up if a Warning is found?

I have this right now:
if ($output_file -cmatch "WARNING:") { | $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell 
$Output = $wshell.Popup("WARNING")}
else

Comment: You just extended your question and you should add that to your original post so it can be addressed, vs in a comment. Anyway, Why to you have a pipe '|' in that if statement. You are not piping anything? It's also not proper to do that, in that manner.  Are you saying what you have is not working? Why you want to do this as a popup? Are you saying you want this to pop an go away, or pop and stay until dismissed by a user? Those are two different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$input_path = 'H:\REPO\ADCLEAN\testlog.log'
$output_file = 'H:\REPO\ADCLEAN\Output.txt'

$content   = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($input_path)
$warnings  = $content.Where( { $_ -like '*WARNING*' } )
[void][System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($output_file, $warnings)
```